# Can a foreign key refer to the primary key of its own table?

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database

I am creating a MySQL employee database for work and I want it to store the supervisor of the employee.

Suppose I have a table called 'employee' with the fields 'id', 'first_name', 'last_name', and 'supv_id' where 'id' is the primary key and 'supv_id' is a foreign key that refers to and employee ID.

Currently I have 'supv_id' as a foreign key that points to a separate table 'supervisor'. This table simply consists of 'id' and 'empl_id' which points back to the employee table. However, if there is a way to simply make 'supv_id' in 'employee' to point to 'employee.id', this would eliminate the need of my 'supervisor' table altogether. Here is an example:

```
+----+--------+-----------+---------+
| id | f_name | l_name    | supv_id |
+----+--------+-----------+---------+ 
|  1 | Han    | Solo      |    NULL | //Or 0?
|  2 | Luke   | Skywalker |       1 |
+----+--------+-----------+---------+
```

In short, I want 'supv_id' to point to another employee. Does this make sense? How would I go about doing this?

Thanks!

Edit: fixed table

Comment: A foreign key can refer to any unique or primary key in any user table (including itself, including compound keys) in any database in mysql (or schema in other dbs)

Comment: `NULL` is the correct value, if there's no match. If you would try to insert zero (0) the result would be a foreign key violation, because there's no id with the value `0`.

Comment: As per answers this is the simplest solution to describe a hierarchy in a relational database, however it becomes difficult to query for arbitrary levels of nodes. You might want to have a look at some of the other data models and think about how you will be accessing the data before commiting to this model.

Comment: @symcbean You kind of went over my head there! This is all still very new to me. For now I am working on the model and design, and eventually I will also create an interface for easy querying. It's still in the early stage so I'm open to any suggestions if you have any. Thanks!

Comment: @VMai Thank you for confirming that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create such a table as following:

```
CREATE TABLE laya2 (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    f_name VARCHAR(20),
    l_name VARCHAR(20),
    supv_id INT,
    INDEX supv_id_idx (supv_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (supv_id)
        REFERENCES laya2(id) 
        ON DELETE SET NULL      -- example for an action
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

My example sets the reference option to SET NULL, because I think it's the logical one here. If an employee who supervises others left, then those employees have no supervisor first. Another option would be to have `NO ACTION` because you could easily identify those employees without a valid supervisor and find a new supervisor for them. `ON DELETE CASCADE` would be wrong here, because those employees won't leave at the same time ...

You could insert employees with

```
INSERT INTO laya2 VALUES
(1, 'Han', 'Solo', NULL),
(2, 'Luke', 'Skywalker', 1);
```

(two successful inserts), but not with

```
INSERT INTO laya2 VALUES
(3, 'Anakin', 'Skywalker', 0);
```

This statement will fail because the foreign key constraint fails.

Deleting Han Solo will change the supv_id for Luke Skywalker to NULL, because of the reference option `ON DELETE SET NULL`

```
DELETE FROM laya2 WHERE id = 1;    -- this will set the supv_id for Luke Skywalker to NULL
```

Comment: Ok that makes sense, thanks a bunch! However I think your second option,no action, is better because my employees belong to different groups with different supervisors so I want to keep them separate for easier updating as opposed to a mixed set of employees with supervisor set to `NULL`. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, join the table to itself. Here's one of many ways:

```
SELECT a.l_name AS employee, b.l_name AS supervisor 
  FROM employee AS a, employee AS b 
  WHERE a.supv_id = b.id             -- link tables
    AND a.id = 2                     -- get employee
```

Returns:

```
employee  | supervisor
----------+-----------
Skywalker | Solo
```

Comment: Hmm it appears there's a problem. I tried this as you said and got the correct output. However upon switching `a.supv_id=b.id` to `b.supv_id=a.id` the output showed that Han Solo's supervisor is Luke Skywalker. How is this possible if Han Solo does not have a supervisor (i.e. `supv_id=NULL`)?

Comment: When you change it to `b.supv_id = a.id` you're changing the "b" table to the employee table and the "a" table to the supervisor table, so you also need to change the labels in the select columns portion.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can define a foreign key that refers to the primary key of its own table.

```
create table employee (id int(10),
                       f_name varchar(10),
                       l_name varchar(10),
                       supv_id int(10)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
alter table employee add primary key (id);
alter table employee add foreign key (supv_id) references employee (id);
```

Employees without supervisor must have NULL in the `supv_id` column.